# Assigning a value to an element of a slice in Python

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment, slice

This is a simple question about how Python handles data and variables. I've done a lot of experimenting and have Python mostly figured out, except this keeps tripping me up:

[edit: I separated and rearranged the examples for clarity]

**Example 1:**

```
>>> a = [[1], 2]
>>> a[0:1]
[[1]]
>>> a[0:1] = [[5]]
>>> a
[[5], 2] # The assignment worked.
```

**Example 2:**

```
>>> a = [[1], 2]
>>> a[0:1][0]
[1]
>>> a[0:1][0] = [5]
>>> a
[[1], 2] # No change?
```

**Example 3:**

```
>>> a = [[1], 2]
>>> a[0:1][0][0]
1
>>> a[0:1][0][0] = 5
>>> a
[[5], 2] # Why now?
```

Can anybody explain to me what's going on here?

So far the answers seem to claim that `a[0:1]` returns a new list containing a reference to the first element of `a`. But I don't see how that explains Example 1.

Comment: Interesting question. Let's see what Alex says. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a[0:1] is returning a new array which contains a reference to the array [1], thus you end up modifying the inner array via a reference call.

The reason the first case doesn't modify the [1] array is that you're assigning the copied outer array a new inner array value.

Bottom line - a[0:1] returns a copy of the data, but the inner data is not copied.

Comment: @dln385: The last sentence of this post answers your question. The inner data (in your case, the number) is not copied, so modifying it changes the original.

Comment: The last sentence explains why `a[0:1][0][0] = 5` works. But `a[0:1] = [[5]]` isn't modifying the inner data, and so _shouldn't_ work. I think it must be handled as a special case, as [pyfunc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055515/assigning-a-value-to-an-element-of-a-slice-in-python/4055556#4055556) seems to imply.

Comment: Yes, when the assignment statetement (i.e., the "=" signal) comes following a slice reference it is a completly different thing than when other operations are done. To be clear: `>>> a[0:1] = [[5]]` is equivalent to `a.__setitem__(slice(0,1,None), [5])` --- while `a[0:1][0] = 5` is the same as: `a.__getitem__(slice(0,1,None)).__setitem__(0, 5)`

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is slicing returns a new object. That is it's return value is a new list.

Hence you can not use an assignment operator to changes the values of the original list

```
>>> a = [[1], 2, 3]
>>> k = a[0:2]
>>> id(a)
4299352904
>>> id(k)
4299353552
>>> 

>>> id(a)
4299352904
>>> id(a[0:2])
4299352832
```

some more plays along the lines

```
>>> k = 5
>>> 
>>> id(k)
4298182344
>>> a[0] = [1,2]
>>> a
[[1, 2], 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
4299352904
>>>
```

[Edit: on second part of question]

```
>>> a[0:1] = [[5]]
```

The following notation is also called commonly as **slice assignment** 
The behavior for builtin lists is atomic (delete + insert) happens in one go. My understanding is that this is not allowed for custom sequence.

Comment: This is correct. Slicing returns a new object. The same is true for assigning dictionary keys to a new variable (e.g. `foo = mydict[bar]`). Changes to the assigned slice do not modify the original reference because they are a copy.

Answer (score 1):

There are three distinct operations with indices, all are translated to method calls:

- `a[i] = b` => `a.__setitem__(i, b)`
- `del a[i]` => `a.__delitem__(i)`
- `a[i]` used as an expression => `a.__getitem__(i)`

Here `a`, `b` and `i` are expressions, and `i` can contain [slice objects](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#index-878) created using the colon shorthand syntax. E.g.:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def __setitem__(self, *a):
...             print a
... 
>>> C()[1] = 0
(1, 0)
>>> C()['foo'] = 0
('foo', 0)
>>> C()['foo':'bar'] = 0
(slice('foo', 'bar', None), 0)
>>> C()['foo':'bar',5] = 0
((slice('foo', 'bar', None), 5), 0)
```

So what's happening in your third example is this:

```
a[0:1][0][0] = 5
```

becomes

```
a.__getitem__(slice(0,1)).__getitem__(0).__setitem__(0, 5)
```

The first `__getitem__` returns a copy of part of the list, but the second `__getitem__` returns the actual list inside that, which is then modified using `__setitem__`.

Your second example on the other hand becomes

```
a.__getitem__(slice(0,1)).__setitem__(0, 5)
```

So `__setitem__` is being called on the sliced copy, leaving the original list intact.